# Get index of character patterns in table

Tags: r, character

There is a table which has two columns with each column having the type character. It is:

```
"FTGS" "JKLP"
"CVVA" "CVVA"
"HGFF" "CVVD"
"CVVD" "HGFF"
"OPSF" "WQSR"
```

...

Can somebody tell me how I would write a function that spits out the index (row number) of a specific combination of characters in column1 and 2? If I enter the function (HGFF,CVVD) it would return 3 and 4 (whether the HGFF or CVVD is in column1 or 2 does not matter). If I enter (CVVA,CVVA) it would be 2. The problem is that it should check accross two columns. Is there a solution in R? Otherwise bash would also be fine.

Comment: I think you meant to say that `(CVVA,CVVA)` would return 0 or `(CVVA,CVVD)` would return 2, right?

Answer (score 0):

A function like the following should work for you:

```
myFun <- function(v1, v2, indf) {
  x <- sort(c(v1, v2))
  which(apply(indf, 1, function(z) all(sort(z) == x)))
}
```

The usage would be like this (assuming your data are in a `data.frame` called "mydf"):

```
myFun("CVVA", "CVVD", indf = mydf)
myFun("HGFF", "CVVD", indf = mydf)
```

In R, the function that it sounds like you are looking for is `which`, but it won't do what you are looking for directly.

Comment: the class of my table is matrix. Will that make a difference?

Comment: @user3419669, did you try it? It should not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to work

```
fun1 <- function(v1, v2, mat) {
ind <- c(0, -nrow(mat))
indx1 <- which(mat == v1) + ind
indx2 <- which(mat == v2) + ind
if (all(sort(indx1) == sort(indx2))) {
    indx1
} else NULL
}

 fun1("HGFF","CVVD", mat) #mat is the matrix
 #[1] 3 4

fun1("CVVA","CVVD", mat)
#NULL
```